# How to pass prop to slot as HTML in vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-slot

I have an alert component

```
<template>
  <div class="notification is-light" :class="type" :style="cssProps">
  <button @click="emitClose" class="delete"></button>
    <slot></slot>
</div>
</template>
```

I want to be able to pass HTML into it via the slot, so that I can define exactly what the alert will look like, for example

```
<Alert v-if="showError" @close="showError = false" maxWidth="600px">
   <span>The next words <b>are bold</b> because of the b tag</span>
 </Alert>
```

The text I'm passing to the slot is rendered as HTML and the  tags work as expected.

However, the text that I want to pass the the alert will be dynamically generated based on a response from an API, so I'm trying to to the following

```
//somewhere in my component javascript
this.error = '<span>Error connecting to your account. Try <b>closing this window</b></span>'
```

Then I'm calling the component as follows

```
<Alert>{{error}}</Alert>
```

This renders the pure text, including the html tags, as opposed to rendering the html tags as in the first example.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you need to use [`v-html`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-html) directive to avoid HTML escaping.
Try

```
<Alert><span v-html="error"></span></Alert>
```

Make sure the content is safe from XSS (doesn't contain any unsafe user input).
Visit [raw HTML documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#raw-html) for more info.

Comment: That's exactly it. Is there a better way to achieve this? are more vue way?

Comment: Apparently there was a `{{{ }}}` interpolation that doesn't escape HTML, but it was deprecated in Vue 2. I don't know the reasons behind it, maybe the authors just wanted to make it a bit more difficult to introduce unintentional security bugs.